# average from sum of numbers

Tags: sum, average

I have to take the average of the following:

10/2 = 5

20/4 = 5

30/5 = 6

(5+5+6) / 3 = 5.333

Why the following does not give me the same result?
(10+20+30) / (5+5+6) is not 5.333

Thanks.

Comment: Why would it give the same result?

Comment: Can apply a formula to calculate the result with the sum?